# P1000: Authentication failed against database server at `localhost`, the provided database credentials for `postgres` are not valid

Tags: postgresql, docker, prisma, pgadmin

Attempting to connect (with pgAdmin4 or attempting a DB migrate with Prisma) to my PostgreSQL running in docker, however, results in the error message

```
Error: P1000: Authentication failed against database server at `localhost`, the provided database credentials for `postgres` are not valid.

Please make sure to provide valid database credentials for the database server at `localhost`.
```

Here are the log message from the docker container `pg_container`:

```
2023-07-10 23:28:55 2023-07-11 03:28:55.532 UTC [84] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2023-07-10 23:28:55 2023-07-11 03:28:55.532 UTC [84] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
2023-07-10 23:28:55     Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

My `docker-compose.yml` :

```
services:
  dev-db:
    container_name: pg_container
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER= postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD= 1234
      - POSTGRES_DB= dev
      
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
```

Running `docker ps` :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                           NAMES
d31b7483c8ad   postgres:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp          pg_container      
fa587cd32a04   dpage/pgadmin4    "/entrypoint.sh"         2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp   pgadmin4_container
```

What I've tried:

1. Try to see if I had a local instance of a postgres running in background, there's nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the list-of-strings form of `environment:` then each item is exactly `KEY=value`, with no whitespace.  If there is whitespace then it is included in the key and/or value.  In your example, the username is  `postgres` with a leading space, and the database name is similarly  `dev` with a space.

You can try entering these credentials with the spaces into PGAdmin or Prisma.

In the Compose file, you either need to remove the spaces

```yaml
environment:
  - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
  #              ^^ no space here
```

or change to the YAML map syntax, which will more consistently use YAML quoting and escaping rules

```yaml
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  #            ^  no leading hyphen, colon between key and value
```